# Container published port accepting TCP connection without anything in container listening

Tags: docker, docker-network

Edit: I found a work around, disabling the userland proxy (docker-proxy) via the daemon.json seems to resolve this. This likely means this is a bug in the docker-proxy and as far as I can tell everything I was running before works correctly.

I am attempting to debug an issue configuring TCP health checks with consul. The configuration of consul etc. isn't relevant as I have isolated this to a rather simple scenario. All containers are connected to bridge0 (config below). Host OS is Centos 7.

What I expect to see is nc from Container 2 to return connection refused but instead it appears to connect and then after sending some random characters a broken pipe. Is this to be expected?

Container 1:

```
[user@192.168.1.2 ~]$ docker run --net=bridge0 -it -p 50032:8000 centos:7 bash
[root@a691f149c045 /]#
```

Container 2:

```
[user@192.168.1.2 ~]$ docker run -it --net=bridge0 centos:7 bash
[root@e9c1cbaf3922 /]# nc 192.168.1.2 50032
asd
asd
Ncat: Broken pipe.
```

Host:

```
[user@192.168.1.2 ~]$ nc 192.168.1.2 50032
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

Docker bridge0 config

```
[user@host ~]$ docker network inspect bridge0
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge0",
        "Id": "b50864883bb2c9482b2d0da595abbe4b12e0de6b7fa91657119316fd75dcac83",
        "Created": "2018-08-16T21:38:11.501721012-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "IPRange": "172.24.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "a691f149c045be06ad90c66221a9c35f2586b75e9a5e2f104c443ced311fdf03": {
                "Name": "gallant_lamport",
                "EndpointID": "e66a16eac8d7a405d3698fa37f6d6a47484b63c9cf07a714bbab6caf107741d6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:09",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.9/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
        "e9c1cbaf3922774183afe613c6641e19346cac8d707bb2374d1251b02855a94f": {
                "Name": "xenodochial_bose",
                "EndpointID": "a01755d0468a2aa188f1b607ee63590bda4dc3e89e15dc78f1556b79fa1aac42",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.10/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: If u are sure about it, you may put an answer, not edit the original question. And you might give Docker a feedback.